# "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-conversion

Good morning. I have the above issue with the following code.

```
SELECT            c.Account_SPID__c [SPID]
                  ,CONVERT(DATE,c.Background_Check_Authorization_Date_Sent__c) [Sent]
                  ,CONVERT(DATE,c.BGC_Completion_Date__c) [Complete]
                  ,c.BGC_Status__c [BGC Status]
                  ,m2.market
                  ,a.billingstate
                  
FROM        SalesForceLocal_Reporting.dbo.Contact c WITH (NOLOCK)

inner join SalesForceLocal.dbo.Account a with (nolock) on c.account_spid__C = a.spid__C
inner join SalesForceLocal.dbo.market__C m with (nolock) on a.market__C = m.id
inner join angie.dbo.markets m2 with (nolock) on m.market_id__C = m2.marketid

where c.Background_Check_Authorization_Date_Sent__c >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
and c.BGC_Status__c in ('pass','fail')
and c.BGC_Completion_Date__c is not null
and c.BGC_Completion_Date__c >= c.Background_Check_Authorization_Date_Sent__c

and c.background_check_authorization_date_sent__C not in 
('2023-04-18 10:45:00:00000')
```

If I leave out the final check for excluding that specific time stamp, it runs fine. But I actually need to exclude all entries from that time. So, the issue is somewhere within entries on that date, but I have been unable to find the malformed string due to the nature of the query, e.g. It is validating what dates are needed, but fails when it gets to the corrupted/malformed entry. If I leave the date verification out in the "where" statement, I get 4M results.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` is your friend here; the result will be `NULL` if the conversion fails. Note that the optimizer is not constrained to first filtering clauses in the `WHERE`, so it is *not* the case that excluding malformed records there will prevent `CONVERT` from failing, as this might happen in an earlier step in the query.

Comment: Will that show me which line in the dbo contains the malformed string?

Comment: If you do a `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(...) IS NULL`, yes.

Comment: fwiw, the datetime literal at the end is not the correct format for SQL Server. For historical reasons, those literals should either be `20230418 10:45:00:00000` (no dashes in the date) or `2023-04-18T10:45:00:00000` (`T` separating date and time portion).

Comment: As an aside, putting `NOLOCK` everywhere is a [bad habit to kick](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Consider using snapshot isolation if it's important that your queries don't block others.

Comment: Also, I assumed the missing single quote at the end of the literal was a simply typo when creating the question rather than part of the actual code, and edited accordingly.

Comment: Also changing `CONVERT` to `TRY_CONVERT` in the opening 'CONVERT' statements resulted in the same error.

Comment: What is the actual defined data type in SQL Server for `background_check_authorization_date_sent__C`?

Comment: Well, you also have `where c.Background_Check_Authorization_Date_Sent__c >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())`, and potentially `c.BGC_Completion_Date__c >= c.Background_Check_Authorization_Date_Sent__c` (depending on the types involved) which can fail for the same reason. Perform all conversions explicitly first. Alternatively, since Salesforce data in custom fields is often quite a big mess, consider first filling a staging table where you convert the raw data into properly typed data so you don't have to repeat these (attempted) conversions in every query, which results in bad query plans.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Correct. Just a missed closing quote when c/p

Comment: Hmm... wondering what happens if you remove a couple of the trailing 0's from the date literal.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you show where to put `TRY_CONVERT` in the above code string?

Comment: @JeroenMostert There are instances on the server where the completed date is before the send date, because of user errors. I don't want to exclude those instances because it borks the analysis that is being run from the query

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used above, so I suspect you wouldn't find an ANSI SQL answer very useful.)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have used that date format for this query for years. There are several other timestamps to exclude that do not cause the error. Only when the specific exclusion of `2023-04-18 10:45:00:00000` do I get the error. 

What I want to find is the entry from that day/time that is causing the error. Then I can just edit it at the source.

Comment: @NathanWenger I used that format for a long time, too, because it _does_ seem to work a lot of the time, especially on english-language data. But it's really not correct, it's contrary to the documentation on what you should do, and eventually it will get you in trouble. And as the first link in my answer demonstrates, it's specifically that literal, rather than any data in the table, that's tripping you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server based on the text of the error, I was able to replicate the issue:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/qqw13556

In short, there are too many 0's at the end of the date literal, and you should do this instead:

```
and c.background_check_authorization_date_sent__C not in 
    ('2023-04-18T10:45:00.000')
```

Also note the extra `T` between the date and time portions, which [really is correct for SQL Server in a way the original is not.](https://%20c.background_check_authorization_date_sent__C%20not%20in%20%20(%272023-04-18%2010:45:00:00000%27))  If you preferred, you could also do it like this:

```
and c.background_check_authorization_date_sent__C not in 
    ('20230418 10:45:00.000')
```

but again: the original format will eventually get you in trouble and you should avoid it.

Comment: This worked. Tested it and there are still entries in there from 4/18, which is good. I want to exclude some of them, not all of them. 

So, something went kablooey on this specific date in terms of the timestamp. To be honest I don't really care which one it is. Moving on...